# middleware on role Zizaco/entrust on controller but if user dont have the role it gives HttpException

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, roles, entrust

So in my laravel project i have 3 roles admin employee vendor and each have theyre controllers in the controllers i have  put the middleware of the role it and it works no problem but i don't like the thing when a user dont have the role it gives HttpException error how i can change instead of giving the user  HttpException redirect him back or to 404 not found page heres my controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('role:employee');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any small customization to exception handling can be done within the render() function of App\Exceptions\Handler.  In this case you might do something like this ... inside that render function.

```
//change all 403's to 404's
if($exception->getCode() == 403){
    throw new NotFoundHttpException();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check if a user has any roles in a closure middleware before the role check happens like

```
// your controller 
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        return !auth()->user()->role ? redirect->back() : $request($next);
    });
    $this->middleware('role:employee');
}
```

Or add a check for the HttpException in the exception handler class and redirect from there.

Comment: well the user has a role but not the right one and i did the redirect from the handler and it worked

Comment: `$request($next)` should change to `$next($request)` for Laravel 5.4, otherwise will have **Function name must be string** issue. Not sure for others Laravel version.